# Adding hours to a timestamp column in Sqlite results in NULL, Why?

Tags: sqlite, datetime

I am getting NULL (nothing) from:

**SELECT DATETIME(ServiceCall_CreatedOn,'-6 hours')  AS 'Service Created On:'** ...

Where ServiceCall_CreatedOn is a Sqlite text column containing:
"2019-01-20 4:48:11" (without the quotes of course)

The following:

**SELECT ServiceCall_CreatedOn  AS 'Service Created On:'** ...

and the following

**SELECT DATETIME('2019-01-20 4:48:11','-6 hours')  AS 'Service Created On:'** ...

do work!!!!!

Why SQLite DATETIME time subtraction work with a date literal and not with the ServiceCall_CreatedOn column on it? What may be a solution?

[image: Problem in one picture]

Comment: `SELECT DATETIME('2019-01-20 4:48:11','-6 hours') AS 'Service Created On:'` doesn't work as the format is incorrect i.e. the hour has only 1 digit not the required two. `SELECT DATETIME('2019-01-20 04:48:11','-6 hours') AS 'Service Created On:'` does work.

Comment: Thanks MiKET! It worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that your issue is that you have an invalid format in that you are using 1 digit for the hour not two.

That is

```
SELECT DATETIME('2019-01-20 4:48:11','-6 hours') AS 'Service Created On:'
```

returns null, whilst

```
SELECT DATETIME('2019-01-20 04:48:11','-6 hours') AS 'Service Created On:'
```

returns **2019-01-19 22:48:11**

e.g.

```
SELECT 
    DATETIME('2019-01-20 4:48:11','-6 hours') AS 'Service Created On: Version1',
    DATETIME('2019-01-20 04:48:11','-6 hours') AS 'Service Created On: Version2'
;
```

results in

[image]

Comment: I tell you I got blinded after hours coding. This was the problem. I think it was me that manually changed the timestamp for troubleshooting and got into a troubleshooting loop. It is amazing the SQLite gives no error, no warning! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

SQLite recognizes specific datetime formats as you can see [here](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).
The format in your case is not one of them.
So you need to reformat the values of the column `ServiceCall_CreatedOn` like this:

```
SELECT DATETIME(
  case when ServiceCall_CreatedOn like '% _:%' 
    then replace(ServiceCall_CreatedOn, ' ', ' 0') 
    else ServiceCall_CreatedOn 
  end,'-6 hours'
)
```

It's not elegant but it works by adding a `0` before the digit of hour only when needed.

Comment: Thanks, the DateTime format got damage when I manually changed the time for troubleshooting purposes. I like your addition to the answer and a possible way to fix a situation where the time format will always be bad. It is not my case, the column is filled by NOW() so I should be OK.